# How To Use Discord.js With Electron

Tags: webpack, discord.js, electron, electron-builder

I wrote an Electron app that uses Discord.js to notify the user by sending embeds. Everything works fine when I run the app using `npm run start`. I used electron-react-boilerplate so the npm scripts can be found [here](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/main/package.json). But I realized that the discord related features stop working when I package my app using the command `npm run package`. Discord related code are located in my main.ts file and I wrote a simple rpcMain event to pinpoint the problem. Here is the code:

```js
import {Client, Intents, TextChannel, MessageEmbed, MessageAttachment} from "discord.js";

ipcMain.on('itemSoldNotifierStatusChange', async (event) => {
  try{
    const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS] });

    event.reply("itemSoldNotifierStatusChange", `${Object.getOwnPropertyNames(client).join(", ")}`);
  }
  catch(err){
    event.reply("itemSoldNotifierStatusChange",`${err}`)
  }
}
```

And the output is:

[image]

As you can see it doesn't have a `login` function. So why does this happen when I package my app.

P.S.: I am using a macbook with M1 pro chip, so I thought maybe this is related to that but I tried packaging the app on a computer that runs on Windows 10 and the same problem occured there as well.

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0",
    "electron-debug": "^3.2.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.4.1",
    "electron-updater": "^4.3.9",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "history": "4.x.x",
    "node-tesseract-ocr": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "screenshot-desktop": "^1.12.7",
    "sharp": "^0.29.3",
    "ws": "^8.3.0"
  },
```